# Hibernate Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, hibernate

I am trying to insert an object in MS SQL with Hibernate if it does not exist in DB.
I called find query method it **returns empty list** but really in table there is this object! As a result, when I call insert method, hibernate want to insert object because it think table is empty so it throw **Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint** !
It works on **Oracle** without any problem. 
Is it maybe caused by my permission or schema or catalog?

```
<property name="schemaUpdate" value="${schemaUpdate}"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <!--<prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${database.schema}</prop>-->
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${database.schema}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">${hibernate.cache.provider_class}</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.query.substitutions">true 'Y', false 'N'</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_outer_join">true</prop>
```

and,

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect

hibernate.show_sql=true
#true: if the database is needed to be created otherwise false
schemaUpdate=false
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update

base.packages=com.cityid
database.schema=dbo

hibernate.cache.provider_class=net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider
REM hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
```

Comment: You have `show_sql` set, so you can see the exact SQL query it's running. Have you tried executing the query manually to see what results you get?

Comment: I execute query manually in MS SQL, It works well and return true tuple!

Comment: And that's with the exact same credentials that Hibernate has?

Comment: for testing purpose, try to check if the object exists in the DB using Native query instead of regular query, native query will make sure no Cache is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned, unique constraint exception is thrown. I think the query you execute is not same as the native query you execute or you have a charset problem.

Comment: Thank you, I have charset problem. I changed value of property in DB from farsi to english so its fixed.